# Flajolet-Martin Algorithm : question about use of certain hash functions

Tags: hashing, streaming-algorithm

this is a question given in a PDF about streaming algorithms (this isnt an assignment but im trying to understand)

> **Exercise 4.4.1** : Suppose our stream consists of the integers 3, 1, 4,
>   1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5. Our hash functions will all be of the form h(x) =
>   ax+ b mod 32 for some a and b. You should treat the result as a 5-bit
>   binary integer. Determine the tail length for each stream element and
>   the resulting estimate of the number of distinct elements if the hash
>   function is:
>
> (a) h(x) = 2x + 1 mod 32.
>
> (b) h(x) = 3x + 7 mod 32.
>
> (c) h(x) = 4x mod 32.
>
> **! Exercise 4.4.2** : Do you see any problems with the choice of hash
>   functions in Exercise 4.4.1? What advice could you give someone who
>   was going to use a hash function of the form h(x) = ax + b mod 2k ?

I have already resolved the first exercise, finding a max R tail length of 0 for (a) and 4 for (b) and (c), therefore the resulting estimation of distinct elements is respectively 1,16,16. (it is not asked to do averages/medians of the hash functions to find a better value)

However, I can't seem to figure the answer to the second exercice ? Is it simply to choose 'a' and 'b' in a certain manner ? or are these functions not good to generate equally randomly numbers with trailing 0s and no trailing 0s ?

Thank you in advance

you can observe the results of each hash functions by running this code : https://onlinegdb.com/rJXC4f4VL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I can't seem to figure the answer to the second exercice ? Is it simply to choose 'a' and 'b' in a certain manner ? or are these functions not good to generate equally randomly numbers with trailing 0s and no trailing 0s ?

You have the right idea. I believe what the question is trying to suggest is that this hash function has a problem with certain values of $a$ and $b$. Consider, in particular, $a = 16$. What will happen to the hash function in that case? How many possible values are there?

So, to pick a good value of $a$, we should probably make sure that $a = 16$ is not allowed. $a = 8$ is not good either. What do you suggest is a good choice for $a$?

Comment: Okay so with the help of your answer (and some rest), I noticed that (a) only returns odd numbers so they will never have trailing zeros, (b) returns both odd and even numbers, (c) only returns even values. You also showed me that if 'a' is a power of 2 this completely narrows the outputs of the hash. So a good hash function would be one that returns both odd/even values while avoiding a = 2^k. Correct ?

Comment: @BenoitF That is correct but you can go one step further :) Whenever $a$ is even (that is what you noticed in the hash functions (a) and (c), as well as in the example $a = 2^k$), the hash function will not return both even and odd values. So you should pick $a$ that is odd.

Comment: Ah okay i see. The question made me think it also had something to do with chosing modulo 2^k but there doesnt seem to be a corelation with 'a' as for example (8x+1) % 17 only returns odd values. Thank you for the help, will accept when i get to a computer (nvm found the checkmark)